# cv2 not showing display through remote desktop

Tags: ubuntu, opencv

I am currently trying to implement a live feed function to my project. I have a function that is supposed to show a live feed of the camera using opencv. When I run the code locally on a intel NUC with ubuntu version 20.04, I am able to see the video feed from the monitor. However when I connect through remote desktop using XRDP, I am no longer able to see the video feed anymore and I did not get any errors. I tried using remote desktop on a raspberry pi with ubuntu version 20.04 and running the code and it works.

I went to check the permissions I have on each device and I found out that my user on the raspberry pi is included in the video groups while my user on the NUC is not included. Could this be the reason why I am not able to see any video feed on the NUC?

This is the function used

```
def live_feed():
global ui_exit_flag
global image_capture_flag

while not ui_exit_flag:
    # Check if image capture is in progress, and if so, pause the camera feed
    while image_capture_flag:
        pass
    #print("UI Thread: Exit flag is " + str(ui_exit_flag))
    success, img = camera.read()
    if success:
        for barcode in pyzbar.decode(img):
            myData=barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
            pts=barcode.polygon
            if len(pts)>=4:
                pts=np.array(pts,np.int32)
                cv2.polylines(img,[pts],True,(255,0,255),6)
                pts2=barcode.rect
                cv2.putText(img,text=myData,org=(pts2[0],pts2[1]),fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,fontScale=0.5,color=(0,244,0),thickness=2)

        cv2.imshow('Press (Q) to close', img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    #else:
        #print("Not showing live")
    #print("Showing Live")
camera.release()
print("UI Thread: No longer showing live")
```